Could someone help me to identify this IC from a servo controller board?
I am trying to identify the component on the image but without success until now. It is part of a servo controller circuit board, there are also two ICs like the one in the first image positioned on the board. Apparently, they are intended to work on the same way. On the first IC is written 7725A and on the other,7726A, however, I could not find any datasheet compatible with this model, I also haven't recognized the manufacturer but I guess it is chinese, given that there are other components from chinese manufacturers on the board.
Figure 1:

Figure 2:


Tip: put "SMD", pin count and part number in the title if you want to attract someone browsing the index and to help future search results.

Those are Dual Power MOSFETs in SOP8 package, the pinout is quite typical.
Based on the markings, most likely one is Dual P-Channel and the other Dual N-Channel.
The manufacturer is "Silicon Wisdom Tech" (Chinese), not sure what their website is, but you can see the matching logo here: https://www.lcsc.com/brand-detail/11407.html

Their website used to be www.siwi-tech.com, but it's dead now and just contains sketchy ads. You can see it in the few datasheets that are available online, like this one.
